# Strange suggested edit from anonymous user

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

I reviewed this [suggest edit](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/21543) by an anonymous user, it looks strange for me, is this normal ? for me it looks like hack, because I can not able to see the user who suggested that edit see the screenshot. Instead it simply shows anonymous user and also he introduce spam like URL.

> [image]

Comment: We allow suggested edits by anonymous users. No problem here. (Also, thank you for rejecting blatant spam. (I mean, BBCode? Really?))

Comment: Looks like spam - and the correct actions happened (It was rejected)

Comment: Spammers will try all sorts of things to get their spam out there. I've even seen spam in tag wikis before.

Comment: Nothing strange. This happens everyday. That's why we have a rejection reason for that which you used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anonymous users are permitted to make suggested edits. Because we have good users standing at the gates preventing the bad edits getting through the spammers largely give up and we are not overwhelmed by these edit suggestions.

You correctly rejected this edit as

> This edit introduces spam, defaces the post in some way, or is
>   otherwise inappropriate.

because it does

Comment: Worth to mention, accidents [do happen](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/208367) - clever spammers can trick even the best of us. So it's important to keep an open eye even on approved edits and catch those.